# Ellipse with a hole

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

How can I create a ellipse (path, ...) with a hole in it:

[image: Ellipse with hole]

The task is to create a visualization of a three-state-indicator. The different states are visualized by rotating the control several degrees to the left or the right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

=>

```
    <Path Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="20">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathFigure StartPoint="80,0">
                    <ArcSegment x:Name="ArcSeg1" Size="100,100" RotationAngle="0" IsLargeArc="True" 
                SweepDirection="Clockwise" Point="20,0"  >
                    </ArcSegment>
                </PathFigure>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
```

There are a few relevant properties here, to understand the math behind it see
http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2008/01/Mathematics-of-ArcSegment.html
But basically you're giving the coordinates of the intersection of two ellipses :[image: intersection]

StartPoint and Point represents the intersecting points, While Size is the size of the full ellipse. The rest is pretty self explanatory. 
If you want to rotate it, the easiest and best way would be to use RotateTransform.

Answer (score 0):

Would making the 'hole' a white triangle on to of the full circle help?  This could be rotated around the center of the circle in conjunction with the 'pointer' (the line).

[image: I can only apologise for my crude rendering]

Comment: I don't know. That's why I'm asking. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [CombinedGeometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.combinedgeometry.aspx) with the `GeometryCombineMode="Exclude"`

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.combinedgeometry.aspx) has a good example.
[image: example of combined geometry]

Comment: As far as I have understood the CombinedGeometry, the second ellipse is also visible because the visibility is controled via the surrounding path and not the two combined geometry objects.

Comment: this is not true. GeometryCombineMode='Exclude' does exactly what it says and a CombinedGeometry is a 'new' geometry calculated from the input. I really think that this is a much more flexible approach then calculating a ArcSegment manually.